# Will my zener diode work again with a polyfuse after a overvoltage?

Tags: diodes, over-voltage-protection, polyfuse

I am trying to make a simple overvoltage & current limiting circuit for my PCB.

I made the following circuit.

[image]

The zener will break down and conduct current to ground. Since its resistance has broken down after reaching its breakdown voltage and it is now conducting, its voltage drops dramatically, so the load in parallel does not receive this excess voltage.

So my question is will the zener diode work again after the polyfuse has been cooled down?

Or do I have to replace it with a new one?
Or are there other options?

Because I really don't wan't to replace a zener diode, not that its much of a work. But I am making this for a friend of mine and he does not have basic knowledge of electronics.

Comment: It depends on the fault conditions, so it's kind of hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the operation of a Zener diode - for a Zener, "breakdown" does not mean damage - its normal operation is in the reverse breakdown region - there it will attemp to maintain its advertised voltage.

In your circuit, the Zener will attempt to limit the voltage to 6.8 volts.  If the input voltage rises above 6.8 Volts, the Zener will draw enough current to "trip" the polyfuse.  If the Zener diode cannot handle sufficient current to trip the polyfuse, it may be damaged.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. One question what do you mean by if the zener will draw enough current to "trip" the polyfuse? The polyfuse will trip at 5 Amps right? Correct me if I am wrong. So will the zener try to draw 5 Amps? Thus damaging it? Because most zener are rated at mA not Amps right?

Comment: I have been looking in the datasheet of the polyfuse. It states that the hold current is 5 Amps and the I trip current is 10 Amps. Does this mean that my zener will be damaged a.k.a flying into the air ?

Comment: @Edris well, you might find out how much smoke is in it.  During the fault condition, the zener will dissipate power proportional to the voltage across it times the current through it, so 10A*6.8V=68W.  How long the zener can survive that will depend on its power rating.  Could be a millisecond, maybe just microseconds.  Whether it is destroyed will depend on how quickly the polyfuse responds (and also on the zener drawing enough power to trip it.  You should set the polyfuse(purchase the appropriate one) so that the trip current is as low as it can possibly be without causing a nuisance trip.

Comment: So calculate the worst case current during intended operation, and find a polyfuse that trips at ~110% of that, or a bit more(~125%) if it's an inductive load like a motor.  If your normal operating current is 50mA, you want a fuse rated/set for 55-60mA

Comment: @KH Thanks for your reply. My PCB is using rgb LEDs. 57 of them. I am assuming for the max. So if the color is set to white. That means that each led draws 20 mA making it 60 mA per LED for rgb. I have 57 of them. 57*0.06 = 3.42 Amps but I have also a ESP32 chip which can draw around 500 mA making it 3.42 + 0.5 = 4 Amps. So I came across a poly fuse of 4 Amps or 5 Amps. Say I would choose the 4 Amps version then I would search for a polyfuse with a I trip current around the 4.4 Amps. But still no solution for the zener. Should I  use a resistor to protect the zener ? Or is that a bad idea

Comment: That's keeping fairly close for your trip value.  Provide links to the datasheets for the zener and polyfuse, it may be possible to figure out how quickly the polyfuse will trip at close to the zener voltage, but I suspect the zener will be too small and it's trip voltage too high.  If it doesn't survive long enough to hit 5A the fuse won't trip.  You're basically building a primitive crowbar circuit.  It may be best just to test it, or to find a higher wattage zener, or if you're willing to put in the effort, look up a better crowbar circuit.

Comment: Because the polyfuse resets, if the zener is destroyed, on the next reset the LEDs will be exposed to full voltage. You'll have to look at the graphs for the zeners, find the worst case *intended* input voltage(5.25 or whatever) and find a zener that has acceptably high resistance at that voltage, and drops off sharply above it.  If the LEDs can potentially run at 0%, the zener will have to pull the full 5A and quickly enough that its own power dissipation doesn't destroy it, especially if it repeatedly resets.  If the LEDs have a minimum current draw, the zener need only make the difference.

Comment: @KH Thanks a lot for your fast reply. I think I am gonna look up a better circuit. You mentioned something about a crowbar circuit. So that's what I am gonna do. For now my question is answered ! Thanks a lot for your time :D

Comment: Ooops.  We're not supposed to completely answer in the comments so now I guess I'll write an answer.  Glad to help.